# Angular image not showing after deploying to Github Pages

Tags: javascript, angular, github-pages

I'm new to Angular. I recently deployed a sample webpage to Github Pages. I was successful at deploying but images that are visible on localhost are not showing up. Instead, I'm getting a 404 logged on the console.

This is the component containing the `img` :

**home.component.html :**

```
<div>
    <img src='assets/images/birthday.jpg' alt='Happy Birthday' width="385px"/>
</div>
```

My directory structure is :

```
   |src
   |--app
   |--assets
    |---images
     |----birthday.jpg
```

The directory structure in the `dist` folder is :

```
   |dist
   |--happy-birthday
    |--assets
     |---images
      |----birthday.jpg
```

I'm deploying using `angular-cli-ghpages` package. My Angular version is `10.0.14`.

Comment: can you share your 404 error ?
like it must have clearly defined the 'image path' that must be missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use `/assets/images/birthday.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly giving a relative path (Path of the `img` relative to `home.component.html`)
An example is given below, this may however change depending on your directory structure.

`<div><img src='../assets/images/birthday.jpg' alt='Happy Birthday' width="385px"/></div>`

Answer (score 0):

I just tried without the leading slash and it worked: `src='assets/images/birthday.jpg'`.